# Wordpress PHP Validate form based on input types

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

So I'm developing a form for wordpress that needs to validate its submitted fields based on the input type. I'm submitting the fields via an array that is passed to a filter, then using that filter to draw up the HTML required to display the form. The form works, but I have no idea how I would validate the fields in this way. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you read http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation or which part in validating a form is confusing?

Comment: hi @RonniSkansing the part I'm having trouble with is validating based on the type of input used in the HTML. The classic way of validation would be to write a script for every field that you are using, but what I'm doing with this form is a little more complex, and I'm trying to build it in a way that it can be reused very rapidly. I'm trying to store the input types in a WP filter and then figure them out that way, but its a little confusing.

Comment: can you use php inside of the wordpress document to validate?

Comment: @CarlosRios how does the link i gave you not suffice

Answer (score 0):

Try [form validator](http://formvalidator.net/). Works good for me.

Comment: This is client side validation.